# ejs-grid get a dialog changing value

Tags: angular, ejs

How to get the current changed value from the dialog, I'm using ejs-grid and when I click to edit I want to get the value I entred in the form so I can PUT Request the back to edit the database [image]

Answer (score -1):

In ejs-grid -u can use actionbegin =>
<ejs-grid (actioncomplete)="change($event>
Write change function in ur ts file then when ever it is edited u will get data in event.data
=>u will get values here in the function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).